# My project was running perfectly, but after reinstall windows, flutter old sdk file deleted, thats why i have install new ver.after that this error

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

- A problem occurred evaluating project ':`flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle`'.

  ```
  No signature of method: build_ypd66ny1zgosb7hln78xzuyp.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_ypd66ny1zgosb7hln78xzuyp$\_run_closure2) values: \[build_ypd66ny1zgosb7hln78xzuyp$\_run_closure2@1a3b2829\]
  ```

  A problem occurred configuring project ':`flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle`'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
  > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

I tried MultiDeskEnabled true

Comment: you have to define the compileSdkVersion in the android/app/build.gradle file

Comment: i did, but still showing this

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your Flutter project after reinstalling Windows and updating your Flutter SDK.

1. The first error is related to the `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` project's `build.gradle` file. The `android` method is not accepting the argument types being passed in. Check the syntax of the `build.gradle` file to ensure that it's correct.
2. The second error is related to the `compileSdkVersion` not being specified in the build.gradle file. To fix it, add the `compileSdkVersion` property to the `android` section of the `build.gradle` file and set it to the appropriate SDK version for your project.

Note that the `MultiDeskEnabled true` command you mentioned is not relevant to your Flutter project and won't help you fix these errors.